# That famous Vivien Thomas suture - what was it?

Tags: medical-history, sutures, reference-request, stitches

Does anyone know what sort of stitch [Vivien Thomas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vivien_Thomas) used that prompted the remark from Blalock, "[this looks like something the Lord made](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_the_Lord_Made)?"

How closely does the modern atrial septectomy resemble Vivien Thomas's work in that respect?

Comment: [A long article discussing it](http://reprints.longform.org/something-the-lord-made-mccabe)